# Zoom error DOES NOT in occur in Internet Explorer, but DOES occur in every other browser I’ve tested

Tags: html, css, layout, cross-browser, zooming

While checking over something else on my college’s website, it noticed that zooming in and out of our website’s pages makes a small gap appear between the header  and the main content   on certain zoom levels.  We mostly test for IE compatibility since that’s what a majority of our visitors use, and when I zoom in and out in IE 9, the gap never appears.  In the current versions of Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and Opera, the same “moving ” error occurs.  It’s not a very bad bug, as it doesn’t affect readability of the site too severely, but it’s something I’d like to eliminate if possible.

What I’ve tried already:

- Making the  that appears to be moving, “content”,  a fixed width
- Giving “content” a fixed position Giving the  inside “content”,    “canvas”, a fixed position
- Changing the z-indexes on “content” and    “canvas” each
- Not setting a position for the header
- Removing a  of class “clear” between s “ct100_header” and “content” (it    just makes the error more extreme)

The site: [www.swic.edu](http://www.swic.edu)

"sw_home.css"

```
/*============================================================*/
/*==================== Left Column ==========*/

/*==================================================*/
/*========== Ads ==========*/

.ad-content
{
    text-align: center;
    margin: 20px 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.ad-content p
{
    text-align:right;   
    padding-right:15px;
    margin-top: -4px;
}

.ad-content img
{
    padding: 5px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #417ec1; /* light blue */
    width: 180px;
}

.ad-content img:hover, .ad_content img:active
{
    border: 1px solid #c2b535; /* light yellow */
}

/*//////////////////// Ads //////////*/

/*////////// Ads //////////*/
/*//////////////////////////////////////////////////*/

/*///////////////////// Left Column //////////*/
/*////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/

/*============================================================*/
/*==================== Main Column ==========*/

/*==================================================*/
/*========== Top Row ==========*/

/*////////// Top Row //////////*/
/*//////////////////////////////////////////////////*/

/*==================================================*/
/*========== Announcements ==========*/

.announcements-wrapper
{
    margin-top: -4px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}

.announcements-wrapper .announcement
{

}

.announcements-wrapper .announcement-last
{
    margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.announcements-wrapper h2
{
    font-size: 18px;
    border-width: 0px 0px 1px 0px;
    border-color: #888;
    border-style: solid;
    color: #771425; 
}

.announcements-wrapper p
{

}

.announcements-wrapper .multicol ul
{
    margin-bottom: 0px!important;
}

.announcement-wrapper img
{

}


/*========================================*/
/*===== Count Down Timer =====*/

.countdown-box
{
/* --COMMENT OUT-- to DISPLAY; --UNCOMMENT-- to HIDE*/

    /*display:none; visibility:hidden;*/

    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    behavior: url(/packages/PIE/PIE_uncompressed.htc);
}

.countdown-box a
{
    color: #417ec1; /* light blue */
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 700;
    font-size: 12px;
}

.countdown-box .en-event-date
{
    font-size: 16px !important;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.countdown-box a:visited
{
    color: #417ec1; /* light blue */
    text-decoration: none;
}

.countdown-box a:hover
{
    color: #b5a933; /* triad yellow; */
}

.countdown-box a:active
{
    color: #b5a933; /* triad yellow; */
}



/* might need implementing in future */

/*////////// Announcements //////////*/
/*//////////////////////////////////////////////////*/

/*==================================================*/
/*========== Bottom Row ==========*/

/*========================================*/
/*===== Widgets =====*/

.widget
{
    padding: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #888;  
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    -khtml-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    position: relative;
    behavior: url(/packages/PIE/PIE_uncompressed.htc);

}

/*===== PollBox =====*/

.widget.poll p
{
    border: 1px solid #888;  
    -moz-border-radius-topleft: 4px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    -khtml-border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-top-left-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    position: relative;
    behavior: url(/packages/PIE/PIE_uncompressed.htc);

    background: #aaaaaa url(/css/images/widget-header-bg.png) 50% 50% repeat-x;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-size: 12px;   
    color: #193c69; /* dark blue */ 
    text-align: center;
}

.widget.poll ol
{
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    left: 0;
}
    .widget.poll ol li {
        font-size: 11px;
        line-height: 15px;
    }
.widget.poll input[type=submit]
{
    /*margin: 0 0 20px 50px;*/
}


/*===== Ektrons Reportchart.css overrides  =====*/

/* /punch ektron in face */
.widget.poll table.tblreport *
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
    color: #222;  
    font-family: Verdana, Sans-Serif;
    line-height:20px;
    font-size: 12px;    
    font-weight: normal;
}

.widget.poll table.tblreport
{
    border-width: 0;
}

.widget.poll table.tblreport .headreport
{
    padding: 0px 3px;
    border: 1px solid #888;  
    background: #aaaaaa url(/css/images/widget-header-bg.png) 50% 50% repeat-x;
    font-size: 12px;
    height: 30px;
    color: #193c69; /* dark blue */ 
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-align: center;
}

.widget.poll table.tblreport td
{
   padding: 0 10px; 
}

.widget.poll table.tblreport .resultbar
{
    background: #005daa; /* swic blue; */ 
}

.widget.poll span.refreshlink
{
    margin: 10px 0;   
    display: block;
}

.widget.poll a.refreshlink
{
   color:  #417ec1!important; /* light blue */
   line-height:20px;
   font-size: 12px; 
   float: right;
   margin: -30px 0 0 0;
}

.widget.poll a.refreshlink:hover
{
    color: #b5a933!important; /* triad yellow; */ 
}

/*///// Widgets /////*/
/*////////////////////////////////////////*/

/*////////// Bottom Row //////////*/
/*//////////////////////////////////////////////////*/

/*///////////////////// Main Column //////////*/
/*////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/


/*============================================================*/
/*==================== Footer Changes ==========*/

.footer p a
{
    font-size: 10px;
}

/*///////////////////// Footer Changes //////////*/
/*////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/
```

"sw_layout.css"

```
/*////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/

/*============================================================*/
/*==================== Header Layout ==========*/

.header {
    height: 140px;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 3;
}

/* because if i use a css3 gradient on the header, it causes z-index issues with the menu because its the relatively positioned object */
.header-bg-wrapper-1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #193c69;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #193c69 0%, #005daa 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#193c69), color-stop(100%,#005daa));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #193c69 0%,#005daa 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #193c69 0%,#005daa 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #193c69 0%,#005daa 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #193c69 0%,#005daa 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#193c69', endColorstr='#005daa',GradientType=0 );
}

.header p {
    color: #fff;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/*==================== Header Row Layout ==========*/
.header .row-1 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
}

.header .row-2 {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
}

/*==================== Header Row 1 Content ==========*/
.header .swic-logo {
    background-color: #fff;
    margin: 10px auto;
    padding: 2px 0px 5px 5px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 170px;
}

    .header .swic-logo a img {
        position: relative;
    }

.header h1 {
    font-size: 30px;
    line-height: 75px;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #fff;
    margin: 10px 0px 0px -20px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.header .header-links-wrapper {
    float: right;
}

    .header .header-links-wrapper a {
        font-size: 14px;
        color: #fff;
    }

        .header .header-links-wrapper a:hover, .header .header-links-wrapper a:active {
            color: #DDB042;
        }

.header .header-icons-wrapper {
    float: right;
    margin-top: 35px;
}

/*==================== Header Row 2 Content ==========*/

/* main menu */

.main-menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    font-family: Arial;
}

.main-menu-bg-middle {
    background: #111;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 100px;
    left: 0;
    height: 40px;
    filter: alpha(opacity=85);
    -moz-opacity: 0.85;
    -khtml-opacity: 0.85;
    opacity: 0.85;
}

/* search box */
.header .search-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    height: 38px;
    text-align: center;
}

    .header .search-wrapper .search-box {
        width: 150px;
        height: 26px !important;
        font-size: 15px;
        line-height: 26px;
        position: absolute;
        right: 40px;
        top: 1px;
        padding: 0 5px;
        margin: 5px 0 0 0;
        background: url(http://www.google.com/cse/intl/en/images/google_custom_search_watermark.gif) #ffffff no-repeat left 50%;
        border: 1px solid #bccdf0;
        border-collapse: collapse;
    }

        .header .search-wrapper .search-box:focus {
            background: #fff;
        }

    .header .search-wrapper .search-button {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 40px;
        height: 40px;
        border: none;
        background: transparent;
        background-image: url('/images/layout/paw-button-angled-up.png');
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
    }

        .header .search-wrapper .search-button:hover, .header .search-wrapper .search-button:focus {
            background-image: url('/images/layout/paw-button-angled-down.png');
            outline: none;
        }

        .header .search-wrapper .search-button:active {
            background-image: url('/images/layout/paw-button-angled-down.png');
            outline: none;
        }

/*==================== Superfish Menu Styles ==========*/

.sf-menu {
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
.sf-menu a {
    padding: 10px 16px;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.sf-menu a, .sf-menu a:visited  { /* visited pseudo selector so IE6 applies text colour*/
    color:          #fff;
}

.sf-menu li li a
{
    padding: 7px 10px;
}

.sf-menu li {
    font-size: 17px;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0!important; padding: 0!important;
}

.sf-menu li ul{
    margin-top: -3px;
    background:     #444; /* fixes IE7 background not behind li border problem */
    width: 12em;
}

.sf-menu li li {
    background:     #444;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: normal;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #555;
}
.sf-menu li li li {
    background:     #555;
}
.sf-menu li:hover, .sf-menu li.sfHover,
.sf-menu a:focus, .sf-menu a:hover, .sf-menu a:active {
    background:     #888;
    color: #b71f38; /* triad red; */
    text-decoration: none;
    outline:        0;
}

/*//////////////////// Header Layout ==========*/
/*////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/

/*============================================================*/
/*==================== Content Layout ==========*/

/*==================== Wrappers ==========*/

.content {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.canvas {
    width: 960px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 16px 0;
}

/*==================== Content Title ==========*/

.content-header-wrapper
{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    margin-bottom: 16px;
}

.breadcrumbs-wrapper
{
    float: left;
    width: 84%;
    height: 20px;
    font-size: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
    overflow: hidden; /* i want to truncate really long breadcrumbs */
}

.email-print-wrapper
{
    width: 16%;
    float: right;
    text-align: right;
    margin-bottom: 4px;
}

.page-title-wrapper
{
    clear: both;
    border-bottom: 3px double #777;
}

.page-title-wrapper h1
{
    margin: 1px; /* fixes corner redraw glitches that pop up sparatically in some broswers as you scoll, ect */
    padding: 4px 4px 4px 4px;
}

/*==================== Side Menu ==========*/

.side-menu-box
{
    border: none;
    background: none;
    padding: 0 5px;
}

.side-menu-box h2
{
    background: none;
    padding: 0 5px;
    color: #771425; /* medium red */
    line-height:29px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #888;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.side-menu-box ul
{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0 0 10px 10px!important;
    left: 0!important;

}
.side-menu-box ul li a
{
    text-decoration: none;
}
.side-menu-box ul li a:hover
{
    text-decoration: underline;
}

.ekflexmenu_accessible_menu_startlink, .ekflexmenu_accessible_menu_endlink, .ekflexmenu_accessible_menuitem_selected_message
{
    display: none;
}

.ekflexmenu_accessible_menu_start
{
    display: none;
}

.side-bar-bg-wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 10px;
    height: 100%;
    width: 220px;
    background: #eee; 
    z-index: -1000;
}

.side-bar-bg-left
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 110px;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -999;
    background: #eee;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(221,221,221,1) 0%, rgba(238,238,238,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(221,221,221,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(238,238,238,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(221,221,221,1) 0%,rgba(238,238,238,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(221,221,221,1) 0%,rgba(238,238,238,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(221,221,221,1) 0%,rgba(238,238,238,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(left,  rgba(221,221,221,1) 0%,rgba(238,238,238,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#dddddd', endColorstr='#eeeeee',GradientType=1 );
}

.side-bar-bg-right
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    left: 120px;
    width: 110px;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -999;
    background: #eee;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%, rgba(221,221,221,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,rgba(238,238,238,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(221,221,221,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%,rgba(221,221,221,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%,rgba(221,221,221,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%,rgba(221,221,221,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(left,  rgba(238,238,238,1) 0%,rgba(221,221,221,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#eeeeee', endColorstr='#dddddd',GradientType=1 );
}

.ekflexmenu_accessible_menu_startlink, .ekflexmenu_accessible_menu_endlink, .ekflexmenu_accessible_menuitem_selected_message
{
    display: none;
}

.ekflexmenu_accessible_menu_start
{
    display: none;
}

/*//////////////////// Content Layout ==========*/
/*////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/

/*============================================================*/
/*==================== Footer Layout ==========*/

.footer {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    background: #005daa;
    /*
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #005daa 0%, #193c69 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#005daa), color-stop(100%,#193c69));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #005daa 0%,#193c69 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #005daa 0%,#193c69 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #005daa 0%,#193c69 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #005daa 0%,#193c69 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#005daa', endColorstr='#193c69',GradientType=0 );
    */
}

.footer-bar-wrapper {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-family: Arial, Sans-Serif;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #005daa;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #005daa 0%, #193c69 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#005daa), color-stop(100%,#193c69));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #005daa 0%,#193c69 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #005daa 0%,#193c69 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #005daa 0%,#193c69 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #005daa 0%,#193c69 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#005daa', endColorstr='#193c69',GradientType=0 );
}

.footer .footer-bar-wrapper p {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 11px;
    margin: 10px 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.footer .footer-links a {
    color: #fff;
}

    .footer .footer-links a:hover {
        color: #EAB73A;
    }

.footer .copyright {
    text-align: right;
}

.footer-campuses-wrapper {
    padding-top: 10px;
    /*color: #fff;*/
    font-size: 11px;

    background: rgb(255,255,255);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(221,221,221,1) 100%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(255,255,255,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(221,221,221,1)));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(221,221,221,1) 100%);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(221,221,221,1) 100%);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(221,221,221,1) 100%);
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%,rgba(221,221,221,1) 100%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ffffff', endColorstr='#dddddd',GradientType=0 );
}

    .footer-campuses-wrapper a:link,
    .footer-campuses-wrapper a:visited {
        color: #417ec1;
    }

    .footer-campuses-wrapper a:hover,
    .footer-campuses-wrapper a:active {
        color: #b5a933;
    }

    .footer-campuses-wrapper .container_12 {
        /*
        border-right: 2px solid #ddd;
        border-left: 2px solid #ddd;
        */
    }

    .footer-campuses-wrapper .campus-inner-wrapper {
        position: relative;
        height: 100%;
        width: 100%;
    }

    .footer-campuses-wrapper .campuses-divider{
        /*
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        right: -10px;
        height: 100%;
        width: 0px;
        border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
        border-left: 1px solid #ddd;
        */
    }

    .footer-campuses-wrapper h2,
    .footer-campuses-wrapper address {
        display: inline;
    }

    .footer-campuses-wrapper h2 {
        font-size: 10px;
        font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;
    }

    .footer-campuses-wrapper h2 a {
        font-size: 10px;
    }

    .footer-campuses-wrapper address {
        font-style: normal;
        font-size: 10px;
    }

    .footer-campuses-wrapper .hlc-logo {
        float: right;
        height: 80px;
        margin-bottom: 10px;
    }

    .footer-campuses-wrapper .google-map-link {
        float: left;
        margin-right: 20px;
    }

    .footer-campuses-wrapper .google-map-link img {
        height: 60px;
        width: 60px;
    }

.footer-bottom-border {
    height: 10px;
    background: rgb(25,60,105); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgba(25,60,105,1) 0%, rgba(0,93,170,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(25,60,105,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,93,170,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgba(25,60,105,1) 0%,rgba(0,93,170,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgba(25,60,105,1) 0%,rgba(0,93,170,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(25,60,105,1) 0%,rgba(0,93,170,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(25,60,105,1) 0%,rgba(0,93,170,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#193c69', endColorstr='#005daa',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
}

/* site toggle button (mobile/desktop) */
.siteToggleButton{
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

/*//////////////////// Footer Layout ==========*/
/*////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////*/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the white gap is the menu items wrapping.  The text is white so you just can't see them doing it.

Add this style to sw_layout.css

```
.main-menu {
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    font-family: Arial;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

While this will get you pointed/repointed in a reasonable direction, the wrapping of menu items in this way could be considered a design limitation, where the content managers need to work within the limitations of their site's design, or the design should change to suite their needs.

If you want, give `width: 101%;` a try.

Comment: The solution that worked for me was setting the width on .main-menu to 108%.  That percentage is just enough to keep things from getting thrown out of position.  Thank you very much for your reply!